# Нужно ли передавать в функцию объект из общей области видимости?

Tags: python

Как правильнее поступить в следующей ситуации? Вот 2 упрощенных примера:

**Вариант 1**

```py
def one_action(a, b):
    return a + b

def two_action(a, c):
    return a - c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a, b, c = 1, 2, 3

    r1 = one_action(a, b)
    r2 = two action(a, c)
```

**Вариант 2**

```py
def one_action(b):
    return a + b

def two_action(c):
    return a - c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a, b, c = 1, 2, 3

    r1 = one_action(b)
    r2 = two action(c)
```

С одной стороны, вроде бы первый вариант логичнее и исключает путаницу, но является ли вариант 2 чем-то зазорным? Можно ли использовать в функции переменную не из ее области видимости?

Comment: Конечно является. Завтра в дополнение к `a` понадобится использовать ещё и `a2`, а послезавтра ещё и `a3` — и всё, второй вариант придётся полностью переписывать. Да и вообще использование глобальных переменных в большинстве случаев — зло

Comment: https://ravesli.com/urok-50-pochemu-globalnye-peremennye-zlo/